# Reduce time till one can mark his own answer as correct

Tags: feature-request, accepted-answer, self-answer

I had a question and found the solution before anyone else. Now I want to mark my own Answer as correct but have to wait 2 days. I think this restriction is pretty useless, since now I will probably forget to mark it correct and others might post answers even though the problem is solved already.

Is there any good reason behind this? Maybe the restriction can be lowered when one has more reputation.

Comment: The main reason is that the existence of an accept mark vastly decreases the likelihood that new answers will come in, possibly a net loss to everyone involved

Comment: I agree in some cases. But thats something the person who asks the question can judge. Some problems have a pretty simple straight forward solution where you don't need more answers. Thats why I think it could be a good Idea to make it based on reputation. I would trust users with e.g. 1k+ reputation to judge about this more than a newbie.

Comment: @Tarion the misconception that you seem to be operating under is that your question is supposed to help you. Your question should actually help the rest of the programming community at large, if you are the only one helped by it then there is a problem. Also, you even being helped by any of the answers is completely a side-effect. Stack Overflow is about helping the entire programming community, not just making your job easier.

Answer (score 12):

The main reason is that the existence of an accept mark vastly decreases the likelihood that new answers will come in, possibly a net loss to everyone involved.

> But thats something the person who asks the question can judge

The OP is the one who had to ask the question in the first place. They are hardly fit to judge the quality of answers.

Plenty of questions get "solved" by a answers which look ok to the OP because they fix their symptoms, but suggest terrible practices.

This limitation is well worth keeping if it helps get those questions get better answers even in only a handful of cases.

Comment: I like this argumentation. I'm not sure, will Stackoverflow remind to solve unsolved questions in future? Than this might be no problem at all.

Comment: You mean whether it'll remind users to accept an answer to their question? I think not - there was a feature that showed the "accept rate" once, but it caused much discontent because users focused on that too much. The accept mark isn't that important in the grand scheme of things.